# Android preferences not working

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I'm new to the amazing world of java, but my Obj-C experince tells me that this code:

```
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot();
String tickets = prefs.get("tickets", "???");
Log.d("Prefs", tickets);
prefs.put("tickets", "!!!");
```

should produce `???` on the first run, and `!!!` on the second run. But it does not. I see  `???` all the time.

What am I missing? Maybe some permissions? Maybe calling some `save()` method on prefs object?

I've also tried:

```
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
```

No luck either.

Comment: why use Preferences.userRoot() if you could use the getSharedPreferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're probably looking for `SharedPreferences`... "`context`" is your `Activity` or `Application`

try:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String tickets = prefs.getString("tickets", "???");
Log.d("Prefs", tickets);
prefs.edit().putString("tickets", "!!!").commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to use SharedPreferences to store some data. In order to write to preferences try this function:

```
public void putPref(Context context, String key, String value){
    SharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

If you want to put the value `"???"` using key `"tickets"` use:

```
putPref(context, "tickets", "???");
```

You can retrieve that value by using:

```
SharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

If you want to get value for the key `"ticket"` use:

```
SharedPrefs.getString("tickets", "default");
```

where `"default"` is the default value if the preference isn't found. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the values to preference using the below function

```
public static void saveTickets(String customerId,Context context) 
        {
            SharedPreferences preferences;
            preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("sample",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            preferences.edit().putString("tickets", customerId).commit();
        }
```

Get the values from preference using the below function. The parameter you need to pass is just context

```
public static String getTickets(Context context) 
    {
        SharedPreferences preferences;
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("sample",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String  customerId = preferences.getString("tickets", "");
        return customerId;
    }
```